# Ionic 3 components disappear on iPhone X device (NOT EMULATOR)

Tags: angular, ionic3

We have an Application that works fine on all Android and most IOS devices. It is only on the iPhone X that components disappear when changing the data it uses to bind. This ONLY happens with the physical device, as I am unable to reproduce the issue on the emulator. The components show back up when I do a pull-refresh. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So I got a hacky workaround to fix this by using Content with an @ViewChild, and putting the following lines of code directly inside the function at the beginning and end respectively:

Beginning

```
this.content.setElementStyle('transform', 'translateY(0)');
```

End

```
this.content.resize();    
this.content.setElementStyle('transform', 'translateY(1px)');
```

It's not ideal, but it does work. I am open to better ideas though.